# 2 way communication between external app and MS Teams

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Problem statement: As a user I want to be able to share information quickly to MS teams from external web application.
For e.g. I am on an application and found some news that might be useful for the team so, I click on share and MS graph apis gets called that lists my teams and channels and I can select a channel to which I wish to share.
And I want this to be 2-way communication i.e. someone from my team can share something from MS Teams with be me that will be visible to me on the web application.

Now as a developer I wish to integrate MS Teams to my webapp such that when a user shares a news to teams, that message is posted by a bot on the teams channel.
And if someone @mentions the bot and provides some text then the bot sends that text to the external web app.

I am aware that this functionality can be achieved even without using a bot by creating webhooks.
But this approach is not viable for me as a outgoing webhook is created at a team level and not on app level according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors). So multiple teams will have multiple outgoing webhooks.

I believe this is possible by using bots or message extensions but I can't find a resource that tells how to build this and MS documentation is not very clear to me.

Comment: You can make web apps suitable with Teams' social and collaborative features, by properly integrating them with Teams.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/samples/integrating-web-apps

Comment: Also Third-party websites can use the launcher script to embed Share to Teams buttons on their webpages. When you select Share to Teams button, it launches the Share to Teams experience in a pop-up window. This allows you to share a link directly to any person or Microsoft Teams channel without switching the context.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/share-to-teams-from-web-apps

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Thank you for answering, I'll check these links out. Also, can you help me with the other way around, sending messages from teams to the web app? I don't understand how the users will be authenticated i.e only those people who are users of the web app can send messages from teams to web app

Comment: You can create subscription for those users who want to send the message.
1.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
2.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-changenotifications-chatmessage#example-3-subscribe-to-messages-and-replies-in-a-chat-without-resource-data

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Can you please help me with the reverse flow too? I wish to send some messages to the external web app. What I've understood from the documentation is that it is possible to trigger external events by using message extensions. Can you please shed some light on this too? Thanks!